# how to attach a replacement soft pad on a Model #32039598 CRAFTSMAN Sander

Tags: repair

how to attach a replacement soft pad on a Model #32039598 CRAFTSMAN Sander. I have the pad just do not see how it attaches,if it needs glued on?

Comment: Does the replacement pad have a paper masking over what would be a self-adhesive surface? It should not be necessary to manually apply glue based on expected marketing and ergonomics.

Comment: A heat gun can be useful for softening the adhesive holding the old pad in place. As @fred_dot_u days, the new one should be self-adhesive.

Comment: There is no adhesive on the soft pad.

Answer (score 1):

This exploded diagram shows a set of screws holding the pad to the motor mechanism.

[image]

Comment: I believe now that the original question applies to the non-removable portion of the sander and not to the abrasive material. This answer is more likely correct. Check the holes to remove collected dust and grime and perhaps screw heads will appear.

Comment: The holes in the soft pad are the same size as the base plate so they do not hold the soft pad on and there is not an adhesive on the soft pad.

Comment: The DeWalt replacements that I'm accustomed to are all one piece--the soft pad comes pre-attached. Is this one of those overseas purchases where you only get part of what you really need?